# Find if an element is between 2 other elements of a list?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

In one of my program, I need to identify if an element is between 2 others to find the prices.
For example for a butcher I have a list of orders, quantity and price.
quantity[5,10,15,20,25]
price[3,2.9,2.7,2.4,2.1]
if for example I have new order of 7 I would like to interpolate the price of of a quantity of 5 and 10 and get 2.95(3+2.9/2)
My problem is not calculate the price but the first step to identify if an element is between 2 others in my list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the list always in ascending order as you show with quantity?

Comment: Yes it's always in the ascending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast method is to make use of bisect from [Python binary search module](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-bisect-in-python/)

Binary search makes complexity is O(log N), where N = len(quantity)

**Code**

```
from bisect import bisect_left 

def binary_search(a, x):
    if x <= a[0] or x >= a[-1]:
        return None            # outside min/max range of a

    i = bisect_left(a, x)

    return None if a[i] == x else i # a[i] == x means on bin (so not between)
```

**Usage**

```
q = [5,10,15,20,25]

for v in range(4, 26, 1):
    answer = binary_search(q, v)
    if answer:
        print('value {} between bins {} and {}'.format(v, answer, answer+1))
    else:
        print('value {} not between bins'.format(v))
```

**Out**

```
value 4 not between bins
value 5 not between bins
value 6 between bins 1 and 2
value 7 between bins 1 and 2
value 8 between bins 1 and 2
value 9 between bins 1 and 2
value 10 not between bins
value 11 between bins 2 and 3
value 12 between bins 2 and 3
value 13 between bins 2 and 3
value 14 between bins 2 and 3
value 15 not between bins
value 16 between bins 3 and 4
value 17 between bins 3 and 4
value 18 between bins 3 and 4
value 19 between bins 3 and 4
value 20 not between bins
value 21 between bins 4 and 5
value 22 between bins 4 and 5
value 23 between bins 4 and 5
value 24 between bins 4 and 5
value 25 not between bins
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be:

If the lists keep their order(always ascending) and there are the same number of items in both lists, you could transform the first list into pairs(tuples) and compare the new number (7) if it's bigger than the first element of the tuple is smaller than the second.

```
data = [5,10,15,20,25]
price= [3,2.9,2.7,2.4,2.1]

tuple_list = [(x, y) for x, y in zip(data, data[1:])]
# [(5, 10), (10, 15), (15, 20), (20, 25)]
```

Then you could operate with the indexes of the tuples:
(but you change it as you prefer)

```
sum_to_calc = 0
new_number = 7

for x in tuple_list:
 if x[0] < new_number and x[1] > new_number:
   for index, y in enumerate(data):
     if x[0] == y or x[1] == y :
        sum_to_calc += price[index]

print(sum_to_calc/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a function that expresses one way of doing what you ask. You have to append the number to the list before running it though:

```
def is_between(lst, val):
    i = 0 # Mark number of iterations
    for lt in lst:
        if lt==val: # If the current value in the list is the one you're looking for
            try:
                assert i!=0 # Check to see if there are any values on either side of it
                lst[i+1]
            except:
                return False
            return True
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution makes the assumption that the quantity list is always in ascending order and it has the same length as the price list.

```py
quantity = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
price = [3, 2.9, 2.7, 2.4, 2.1]

# Could be quantity or price
list_length = len(quantity)

subtotal = 0

# Number you want to check
number = 7

for x in range(list_length):
    if x+1 == list_length:
        break

    if quantity[x] <= number and number <= quantity[i+1]:
        subtotal += price[x] + price[x+1]
        break

if subtotal:
    total = 2.95 * (subtotal / 2)
else:
    # Do something
    pass
```